# two foreign keys of same table (match between two profiles) in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i'm facing problems to realize a relation. I have a table "match_profils" and "profils". "match_profils" contains two "profils" foreign keys. I have problem to do the relation with Models.
Here is my model :

```
class MatchProfil extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    public $timestamps = FALSE;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','profil_id2','etat',
    ];


    public function  profilEtudiant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\profil')->where('profil.id','=','match_profils.id');
    }

    public function profilRetraite()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\profil')->where('profil.id','=','match_profils.profil_id2');
       }
}
```

And Profil Model :

```
class Profil extends Model
{


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'nom', 'prenom', 'mail_famille', 'telephone_famille', 'propositions_passions', 'propositions_activites','avatar','type',
    ];
    /**
         * Get the comments for the blog post.
         */
        public function activites()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activite', 'activite_profil');
        }

        public function passions()
        {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Passion', 'passion_profil');
        }

        public function autrePassions()
        {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\AutrePassion', 'autre_passion_profil');
        }

        ....


        public function matchEtudiant()
        {
        return $this->hasOne(MatchProfil::class, 'id');
        }

        public function matchRetraite()
        {
        return $this->hasOne(MatchProfil::class, 'profil_id2');
        }


}
```

The problem is when i try to save a match like this :

```
$match = new MatchProfil(['etat' => 'en attente']);
                   $profilDBEtudiant = Profil::find($profilEtudiant);
                   $profilDBRetraite = Profil::find($profilRetraiteMeilleur);

                   $profilDBEtudiant->matchEtudiant()->save($match);
                   $profilDBRetraite->matchRetraite()->save($match);
```

The profil_id2 field stay null on database how i'm suppose to realize correctly this relation ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It's simple first i named the field "id" (in the first post)  as "profil_id1" for students profile but when i saw that the record for matchEtudiant() and matchRetraite() needed a field "id" to be updated i renamed field "profil_id1" into "id" but that didn't solved the problem of the update of matchRetraite().
So, i just put an **extra field "id" with auto increment** in database and renamed the "prior id for student" to "profil_id1". Now classes looks like this : 
The class Profil :

```
  public function matchEtudiant()
        {
        return $this->hasOne(MatchProfil::class, 'profil_id1');
        }

        public function matchRetraite()
        {
        return $this->hasOne(MatchProfil::class, 'profil_id2');
        }
```

And the class MatchProfil :

```
public function  profilEtudiant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\profil')->where('profil.id','=','match_profils.profil_id1');
    }

    public function profilRetraite()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\profil')->where('profil.id','=','match_profils.profil_id2');
    }
```

And that did the trick. It's ok now for my relation.